# xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl) error

Tags: javascript, xslt

I try to replicate the example [Transforming XML to XHTML in the Browser](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp), but I have an error at the line `xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl)` in the consol, and nothing appear in my browser.
I uploaded the 3 files needed on my server :

1. [The XML catalog](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cdcatalog.xml)
2. [the XSL file](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cdcatalog_client.xsl)
3. [the html file with the javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_cdcatalog)

all of them are copied from the w3schools website.

Why I cannot replicate that example ?

Comment: Are you using Chrome browser?

Comment: no, Firefox 60. and IE also find an error

Comment: The W3C website is https://www.w3.org/, the site you have linked to is not in any way related to the W3C, other than that they have choosen to use the abbreviation in its name. You haven't explained which error exactly you get and you haven't provided a link to your server so that we could check.

Comment: I deleted the reference to W3C since w3schools has no association with W3C, they just chose a name that makes people think they have.

Comment: the link to my server : [temp](http://perso.univ-mlv.fr/larrieu/web/)  ; 
the first error `Erreur d’analyse XML : instruction de traitement XML ou texte pas au début d’une entité externe  Emplacement : http://perso.univ-mlv.fr/larrieu/web/stylesheet.xsl Numéro de ligne 2, Colonne 1`  ; 
the second error : `TypeError: Argument 1 of XSLTProcessor.importStylesheet is not an object` ; 
@MartinHonnen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load http://perso.univ-mlv.fr/larrieu/web/stylesheet.xsl directly in a browser and it will tell you that it is not well-formed XML, e.g. Chrome indicates "error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document". So you need to correct that stylesheet to start directly with the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` or you need to omit it, it is only allowed at the start of an XML document.

Additionally the XSLT http://perso.univ-mlv.fr/larrieu/web/stylesheet.xsl selects e.g. `catalog/cd`, that is, element with names all in lower case, while the XML http://perso.univ-mlv.fr/larrieu/web/cd_catalog.xml you use, has all elements names in upper case (e.g. `CATALOG`), so the XSLT does simply not select those elements. You will need to ensure you use the same case and spelling for node names in the XML and XSLT.

Comment: ok, thanks, I delete the first empty line and the error on the XSL file has left [xsl file](http://perso.univ-mlv.fr/larrieu/web/stylesheet.xsl). But the XML data do not appear on the [html page](http://perso.univ-mlv.fr/larrieu/web/)

Comment: See the edit of the answer, case of letters matters in XML and there with XSLT and XPath, currently the case of your XPath selection does not match the element names in the input XML.

Comment: thanks, I 've learn that w3schools has no link with the W3C, and that their examples have some errors ...